# HTML Div To Scroll to Another Div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 1 Div, "read-more hvr-pulse" and I wish for an event to occur when a User Clicks that DIV. I want it to scroll to another Div which is a login form down the page.

I have attempted a  which surrounded the DIV But that caused several issues with the styling, and at the end of the day it did not work. I am reasonably new to JS, so simplicity would be amazing.

The DIV that holds the login is called, "eUser"

Basically I just want the DIV "read-more hvr-pulse" to scroll to "eUser" smoothly. Any Help at all would be appreciated.

**HTML**

```
<div class="Main animated fadeIn">
    <!--To make the Site Unique, I have included Several Trailers for the Main Landing Page !-->
    <video autoplay loop poster="polina.jpg" id="bgvid">
        <source src="img/indexMV.webm" type="video/webm">
        <source src="img/indexMV.webm" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
<!--For Style Purposes, I have wrapped the Login and Register Section of the site in a Container !-->
<div class="eUser">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="login animated bounceInDown" >
            <form class="form-3" action="logreg.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
                <label>Username: </label><input type="text" name="username" value="" placeholder="Username">
                <br />
                <label>Password: </label><input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password">
                <br />
                <input class="Login hvr-pulse" type="submit" name="login" value="Login">
                <input class="Register hvr-pulse" type="submit" name="register" value="Register">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- The code below is The Text for the Landing Page -->
<section class="start-page parallax-background" id="home">
    <div class="content">
    <div class="text">
    <h1>Welcome to our User Login Page. Please Select Your User Type</h1>
    <hr/>
    <div class="read-more hvr-pulse">New User</div>
    <div class="eUser hvr-pulse">Existing User</div>
    <div class="Admin hvr-pulse">Admin</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [**`animate()`**](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function and `scrollTop` to smoothly scroll to some element.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.read-more.hvr-pulse', function(){
  $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('.eUser').offset().top
  },'slow');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Main animated fadeIn">
    <!--To make the Site Unique, I have included Several Trailers for the Main Landing Page !-->
    <video autoplay loop poster="polina.jpg" id="bgvid">
        <source src="img/indexMV.webm" type="video/webm">
        <source src="img/indexMV.webm" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
<!--For Style Purposes, I have wrapped the Login and Register Section of the site in a Container !-->
<div class="eUser">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="login animated bounceInDown" >
            <form class="form-3" action="logreg.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
                <label>Username: </label><input type="text" name="username" value="" placeholder="Username">
                <br />
                <label>Password: </label><input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password">
                <br />
                <input class="Login hvr-pulse" type="submit" name="login" value="Login">
                <input class="Register hvr-pulse" type="submit" name="register" value="Register">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- The code below is The Text for the Landing Page -->
<section class="start-page parallax-background" id="home">
    <div class="content">
    <div class="text">
    <h1>Welcome to our User Login Page. Please Select Your User Type</h1>
    <hr/>
    <div class="read-more hvr-pulse">New User</div>
    <div class="eUser hvr-pulse">Existing User</div>
    <div class="Admin hvr-pulse">Admin</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.animate` jQuery function

[HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lmg62b2/) is a fiddle

Please note that `CSS` from the fiddle above is just for testing. You should take into consideration left side of the screen ( html & js )

```
$(function(){

  var $readMore= $('.read-more');
  var $eUser=$('.eUser');

  $readMore.click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $eUser.offset().top
    }, 800);
  })

})
```

Btw, why don't you use `buttons` instead of `divs` for such kind of actions  ? ( new user and so on )

Comment: Great answer, but did you mean use buttons instead of divs at the end there? In the original code OP is using divs!

Comment: Yes. I said it as a suggestion. I mean it's better to use a button because you're binding an event on that, an event which is triggered by user interaction. Div is a container.

Comment: No no, I understood! I mean in your answer, you said them the wrong way round (buttons instead of divs, not divs instead of buttons).

Comment: I don't seem to be having any luck with either solutions unfortunately. I have created a FIDDLE which may be of use? https://jsfiddle.net/jr9gnxgg/2/

Comment: Here is a new an updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jr9gnxgg/4/ . Please not e that I made it to show you it works, but you have some html & css problems, you have to fix yourself. First of all you have multiple `eUser` elements on your page. Another aspect is that your `eUser div container` has no height.